# Insert empty value as input

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Running [`sphinx-quickstart`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/tutorial.html) I've been asked:

```
> Name prefix for templates and static dir [_]:
```

The default value is `_` but I don't need a prefix.

How can I insert an empty value in a prompt input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke [`sphinx-quickstart --dot=`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-quickstart-dot). Then the option will not be presented in the prompts and your `conf.py` will have the configuration values set:

```
templates_path = ['templates']
html_static_path = ['static']
```

...as well as for other builders you specify.

You can also edit those values in your `conf.py` afterward.

Or you can override options in your `conf.py` when invoking Sphinx with the [`-D` option](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#id2).

```
sphinx-build [options] sourcedir builddir [filenames]
sphinx-build templates_path=templates html_static_path=static sourcedir builddir [filenames]
```